# Python text to speech not working using pyttsx3

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

```
import pyttsx3
engine=pyttsx3.init('dummy')
engine.say('Hello')
engine.runAndWait()
```

While I am executing the following code, I am not getting any errors but I am not getting any voice from the system.Help me what I want to do.

Comment: It should be engine=pyttsx3.init(), just remove 'dummy' and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("Hello")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually 'dummy' is a test driver that does not do anything. Try using 'sapi5' or leave it empty.
`import pyttsx3 engine=pyttsx3.init('sapi5')`

(or)

`import pyttsx3 engine=pyttsx3.init()`

Hope it works!

Comment: Tq all ,it woking fine now